# convert java example from GET to POST

Tags: java, android, http, post, get

im not experienced in java and i got a working example code for some XML interaction, my only problem is that i need to POST data (username/password)

the relevant code is:

```
static String myUrlString = "http://www.grupoandroid.com/interface/mobile/index.php";
protected TheParser(){
    try {
        this.myUrl = new URL(myUrlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}



protected InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
        return myUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be relevant to what your question asks - where's the GET? And I don't understand how code for XML interaction is going to help you - does it read or write XML to the server?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
protected InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = new HttpURLConnection(myUrl);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //writeout data to the output stream
        return con.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using an http-client library, rather than parsing the full http stack yourself.

[apache-http-client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga)
  [hotpotato](http://hotpotato.biasedbit.com/)

You can find enough examples and tutorials in the web for these.

Comment: Especially, since the apache http library is already included in the android runtime.